# Django REST - Resolving Foreign Keys and M2M's in a Serializer

Tags: json, django, rest, serialization

I have the following Models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Achievement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class UnlockedAchievement(models.Model):
    achievement = models.ForeignKey(Achievement)
    date = models.DateTimeField()    

class PlayerAchievements(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    unlocked_achievements = models.ManyToManyField(UnlockedAchievement, related_name="unlocked_achievements", blank=True, null=True)
```

With a PUT, I'm trying to resolve both the Player's foreign key as well as the nested relationship of all the Achievements. My JSON data effectively looks like this:

```
{"name":"playername",
    "achievements":
    {
        "ach1":"timestamp",
        "ach2":"timestamp",
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is the magic combination of which kinds of Serializers to use and, when using them, which serializer fields or nested Serializers to use to be able to resolve Players by **name**, and the unlocked achievements (and then their Achievement foreign keys) by providing a name.

In this case I don't have access to id numbers, hence why things are done by names.

Such a strange mixture it seems. Can anyone lend a hand? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#nested-relationships) to fully include the serialization of a related model:

```
class AchievementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Achievement

class UnlockedAchievementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    achievement = AchievementSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UnlockedAchievement

class PlayerAchievementsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unlocked_achievements = UnlockedAchievementSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PlayerAchievements

class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    player_achievements = PlayerAchievementsSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Player
```

Then just filter the `Player` object by name and serialize it.

Comment: I mostly understand how that all works, thank you for the clarification. However, I'm equally as stumped on what the proper view would look like in order to achieve the PUT/POST utilizing these nested relationships. Could you lend a hand with that as well? Many articles I found lately (of about a year ago) mention this is very WIP. I'm not sure if that's gotten better with more recent version of Django or not.